# Different results using Matlab fft2 and MKL DftiComputeForward

Tags: matlab, intel-mkl

I have different results trying to compute Forward Fourie Transform for 2D data.

Simple test example for 3x3 matrix below:
Matlab, listing:

```
fft2([25.6798, 26.0815, 29.0069; 33.5761 37.123 38.4696; 38.6358 38.0078 37.649])
```

Matlab result:

```
ans =
   1.0e+02 *
   3.0423 + 0.0000i  -0.0528 + 0.0339i  -0.0528 - 0.0339i
  -0.3096 + 0.0444i   0.0112 + 0.0646i  -0.0144 + 0.0225i
  -0.3096 - 0.0444i  -0.0144 - 0.0225i   0.0112 - 0.0646i
```

MKL, listing:

```
DFTI_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE descriptor1;  
double test[3][3] = {{25.6798, 26.0815, 29.0069},
                      {33.5761, 37.123, 38.4696},
                      {38.6358, 38.0078, 37.649}};  
MKL_LONG status1, l1[2]; l1[0] = 3; l1[1] = 3;  
MKL_Complex16 fftu1[3][3];

status1 = DftiCreateDescriptor(&descriptor1, DFTI_DOUBLE, DFTI_REAL, 2, l1);  
status = DftiCommitDescriptor( descriptor1);  
status = DftiComputeForward( descriptor1, test, fftu1);
```

MKL result:

```
4.02248e-315+2.35325e-310i 6.42285e-323+6.95254e-310i 2.35325e-310+2.35325e-310i
6.95254e-310+6.95254e-310i 2.35308e-310+2.35325e-310i 0+2.35325e-310i
2.35325e-310+2.35325e-310i 2.35325e-310+2.35325e-310i 7.41098e-323+1.03754e-322i
```

I have found that the problem may be caused by descriptor, the output storage configuration in MKL case. But I can't find the correct way of setting this descriptor.

What Am I doing wrong? Please, give me some hint.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've got it. May be the solution would be useful for someone.

The correct C++ MKL listing is provided below with clarification comments.
First, the next definition should be used in the including section:

```
#include <complex>
#define MKL_Complex16 std::complex<double> //This definition should be done before including MKL files. You will need it to use STL functions, for example conj, with MKL_Complex16 data
#include "mkl.h"
```

Second, the DFTI_NOT_INPLACE and DFTI_STORAGE should be defined for this case, in addition to code in the question:

```
DFTI_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE descriptor1;  
double test[3][3] = {{25.6798, 26.0815, 29.0069},
                      {33.5761, 37.123, 38.4696},
                      {38.6358, 38.0078, 37.649}};  
MKL_LONG status1, l1[2]; l1[0] = 3; l1[1] = 3;  
MKL_Complex16 fftu1[3][3];
status1 = DftiCreateDescriptor(&descriptor1, DFTI_DOUBLE, DFTI_REAL, 2, l1);
status = DftiSetValue(descriptor1, DFTI_PLACEMENT, DFTI_NOT_INPLACE);
status = DftiSetValue(descriptor1, DFTI_CONJUGATE_EVEN_STORAGE, DFTI_COMPLEX_COMPLEX);  
MKL_LONG rs[2]; rs[0] = 0; rs[1] = 3; rs[2] = 1; //describing 2D 3x3 matrix
status = DftiSetValue(descriptor1, DFTI_INPUT_STRIDES, rs);
MKL_LONG cs[2]; cs[0] = 0; cs[1] = 3; cs[2] = 1; /*Describing output matrix. Warning! Only N1x(N2/2)+1 half part will contain correct answer. Rest part should be restored!!! According to the manual, cs[1]=N2/2+1, so cs[1] should be 2 in our case. But if cs[1]=2, this leads to results shift in answer.. I hope, this is (making cs[1]=N2} is a correct way to deal with shift, bu i'm not sure there. Need to be checked*/
status = DftiSetValue(descriptor1, DFTI_OUTPUT_STRIDES, cs);
status = DftiCommitDescriptor( descriptor1);  
status = DftiComputeForward( descriptor1, test, fftu1); // Forward Fourie done
/*Now the complex-valued data sequences in the conjugate-even domain can be reconstructed as described in https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-dfti-packed-format*/
for (size_t ii=0; ii< 3; ii++){
   for (size_t jj=3/2+1; jj< 3; jj++){
     fftu1[ii][jj] = std::conj((MKL_Complex16)fftu1 [(3-ii)%3] [(3-jj)%3]);
   }
}
```

Now the fftu1 results are the same as for Matlab computation up to the fourth decimal place.